# Count the number of lines in a text file while its still being written

Tags: java, text, line-numbers

I have a `java` program that creates a text file as follows:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(filename + ".txt");
BufferedWriter outwriter = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```

I add lines to the file by using

```
outwriter.write("line to be added");
```

Now at certain stages of the program I need to know how many lines I have added in the text file, while the file still has lines waiting to be added.

This whole process is to add some footer and header.

Is there any method that can find the **current** or **last added** line number?

> **EDIT**

Adding a `function` or a `counter` to add lines is a solution but the time constraint doesn't allow me that. As I am dealing with hell lot of `LOC` this would be a major change at a lot of places it would consume a lot of time.

Comment: You'll need to keep a counter of the lines you have added, taking into account the line ending (ie `\n`) of the text being written

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Apache Commons Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html).

It will perform a `tail`-like operation and call you back (via [TailListener](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/TailerListener.html)) for each line as lines are added to the file. You can then maintain your count in the callback. You don't have to worry about writing file reading/parsing code etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just implement your own writer, e.g. `LineCountWriter extends Writer` that wraps other `Buffered` and counts written lines.

Answer (score 0):

Make a counter:

```
lineCounter+="line to be added".split("\n").length-1
```

Comment: I have 35000+ lines of code where I need to add them...So that is not a feasible solution...

Comment: Make a function as described in the other answers

Answer (score 0):

Make a method which will write lines to the files

```
private static int lineCount;
private static void fileWriter(BufferedWriter outwriter, String line)
{
    outwriter.write(line);
    lineCount++;
}
```

Now each time you need to write a line to a file, then just call this method. And at any point in time you need to know the line count then `lineCount` variable will do the concern.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like this:

```
public int writeLine(BufferedWriter out, String message, int numberOfLines) {
    out.write(message);
    return numberOfLines++;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
int totalLines = 0;
totalLines = writeLine("Line to be added", outwriter, totalLines);

System.out.println("Total lines: " + totalLines);

> "Total lines: 1"
```